# Does Ready API generate DLL files in the backgroung while it's in use?

Tags: ready-api

I am using ReadyAPI tool in my work machine and seeing the some dll files generated by ReadyAPI are being blocked by carbon in my company's netwrok.

Can someone please advise me If ReadyAPI tool generates dll files in the background while it's being used.
If yes, how to configure that to get generated in a single folder, so that I can get exemption for that folder to remain unblocked.

Attached the error message while using Ready API.    [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owvc2.png)

Comment: Have you check with customer support of smartbear team?